# how to create some divs which has the same stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code. I want to get a dynamic div content list in my 'content1' div.
For example. When this page started loading, I would do an ajax request to get some info. According the info, create some divs (the number of divs is from info array's count) which has the same stylesheet as 'accountContent' div but has different content.

```
<div class="main">
  <br>
  <div id="content1" style=" border-radius: 8px; width: 100%;margin: auto; background-color: white;-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;  ">
    <br>
    <div class="accountContent">
      <div style="width: 95%;margin: auto; background-color: rgb(245,245,245);height: 40px;border-radius: 10px">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <p style="width:95%; margin: auto">公众号名称</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <p style="width:95%; margin: auto">接入状态：</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 5px; ">
          <button type="button" class="button button-small button-plain button-borderless" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="删除" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-times" style=" color: #101010"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 95%;margin: auto; background-color: white;height: 50px;border-radius: 10px">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <img src="images/default.jpg" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;border-radius: 20px;float: left">
        <div style="margin-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;float: left"><p>物管助手</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <p style=" margin-left: 12px;float: left">接入成功</p><i class="fa fa-check" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 2px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <a href=# class="button button-pill button-tiny button-border " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="编辑公众号信息" style=" height: 36px;float: right;"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="padding-top: 11px;"></i> 编辑</a>
        <a href=# class="button button-pill button-tiny button-border" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="管理公众号功能" style="height: 36px;float: right;margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-wrench" style="padding-top: 11px;"></i> 功能管理</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

It shows as in this screenshot:
[image: I want to get more divs like this kind]

Answer (score 1):

Any markup you add to your page will be styled with the CSS rules already applied to the page. In your case it sounds like you simply need to apply `.accountContent` to those new DIVs.

You do not have to create a stylesheet for them. If they have different styles than those already on the page, simply add the CSS selector that you've applied to those new DIVs in your current CSS file. When the Ajax adds the new DIVs to the page they will by styled according to the selectors they match.